# Custom circular bar using MUI5 with React

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx, progress-bar, mui-x-charts

I would like to make something similar the picture. But I tried and I am not even getting close to the result. All the data are dynamic but it's for the design I am lost.

Thank you if somebody can at least tell me how to make something similar.

Thank you for your help :)

Have a nice day[image]